# Dudas en operacion

Tags: java

¿Alguien me podría dar una breve explicación sobre el porqué de los resultados de estas operaciones?

```
System.out.println(1<<4);
System.out.println(1>>4);
System.out.println(5>>2);

16
0
1
```

Aquí dejo [enlace](https://ideone.com/9gyVz8) en donde los probé.

Comment: Esto te ayudará : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_bitwise_operators_examples.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Son operadores a nivel de bits

```
<<   desplazamiento a la izquierda, rellenando con ceros a la derecha
>>   desplazamiento a la derecha, rellenando con el bit de signo por la izquierda
```

Realizan la manipulación de los bits de los datos con los que operan. Los datos deben ser de tipo entero.

> 1 << 4  significa --> desplaza el valor en bits 01 cuatro posiciones a la izquierda, completanto con ceros a la derecha. Lo que es igual a 10000 que es 16.
>
> 1 >> 4 --> desplaza 01 a la derecha cuatro veces, completando con
> ceros, lo que da lugar a un valor de cero.
>
> 5>>2 --> desplaza el valor 101 2 veces a la derecha, completando con
> ceros por la izquierda --> 001, que es 1

Más info en el [enlace](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_Java/Operadores_de_bits)

Comment: Gracias... esta bien completa la información del link.

Comment: ¡De nada! En la respuesta de @Alejandro Ricotti tienes más información

Comment: Si aceptas una respuesta das reputación a la persona que ha respondido

Comment: Actualmente no me permite, solo hasta 15 de reputación, pero lo tendré en cuenta

Answer (score 3):

```
'>>': desplazamiento a la derecha de los bits del operando
'<<': desplazamiento a la izquierda de los bits de operando
```

**<< "Desplazamiento a la izquierda"**

Deseamos correr el número 33 dos posiciones a la izquierda. Entonces realizamos :

```
int j = 33;
int k = j << 2;
```

Este es el resultado:

```
00000000000000000000000000100001 : j = 33
00000000000000000000000010000100 : k = 33 << 2 ; k = 132
```

Cada "hueco" que queda a la derecha tras correr este número se rellena con ceros. Los bits a la izquierda se pierden, no es una operación de rotación. Si prestamos atención, observaremos que esta operación multiplicó a j por 2 tantas veces como posiciones se ha desplazado. En este caso se multiplicó por 4 ( 2 x 2 ). Hay que notar que el signo del número puede cambiar tras la operación (por ejemplo 1 << 31 = -2147483648).

**>> "Desplazamiento a la derecha"**

Volvamos a colocar como estaban los bits del caso anterior. Queremos obtener nuevamente el número 33. Para esto desplazamos el número 132 dos posiciones a la derecha.

```
int k = 132;
int m = k >> 2;
```

Como resultado obtenemos el número original.

```
00000000000000000000000010000100 : k = 132    
00000000000000000000000000100001 : m = 132 >> 2 ; m = 33
```

Podemos ver que el corrimiento a la derecha realiza una división de enteros. Divide por 2, tantas veces como posiciones desplazadas.

Veamos que ocurre si pretendemos realizar un desplazamiento a la derecha con un número negativo. Tengan en cuenta que la representación de números es de complemento a 2. Si tengo una variable de tipo int con el valor –1 , internamente está almacenada de la siguiente forma :

```
11111111111111111111111111111111 : -1 complemento a 2
```

https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_Java/Operadores_de_bits

Comment: Tu información fue muy util